# MySQL Store large number with many decimal places

Tags: mysql

I'm somewhat confused on defining the correct definition for a float table column. This is required to create a database table to store large numbers which have up to eight decimal places. I need to be able to store anywhere from and between the following two.

0.00000001 - 10000000

Would that be defined as float(16) as the argument is the maximum number of digits that need to be displayed. Perhaps I have misunderstood the column definition entirely.

Answer (score 1):

[`FLOAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/floating-point-types.html) is approximate datatype and  I would not recommend it to use for storing exact values.

For storing exact numbers you should use [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col DECIMAL(20,10));
```

Should be more than sufficent for your needs.